# link against some existing belongsToMany records, and create new ones

Tags: cakephp-3.0

The cookbok says:

> If you need to link against some existing belongsToMany records, and create new ones at the same time you can use an expanded format:

```
$data = [
    'title' => 'My title',
    'body' => 'The text',
    'user_id' => 1,
    'tags' => [
        ['name' => 'A new tag'],
        ['name' => 'Another new tag'],
        ['id' => 5],
        ['id' => 21]
    ]
];
```

My question is what should be the **name property** for the *tag* input to get an array like this for the request data?

Or should I just have a name=tags[name] and than change it in beforeMarshal?

Comment: How about `tags.0.name`, `tags.1.name`, `tags.2.id`, `tags.3.id`? Not sure if I really got your problem.

Comment: @ndm Thanks. It was just this simple...